# mysql sub query in a pdo loop

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following pdo query for uploading a csv to mysql:

```
private function loadRecurringData ( $filepath, $table )
{

    //We are going to insert some data into the users table
    $sth = $this->dbcon->prepare(
        "INSERT INTO " . $table . "(cust_acc, cli, charge_date, quantity, wholesale_cost, charge_code,description, retail) 
        VALUES (:cust_acc, :cli, :charge_date, :quantity, :wholesale_cost, :charge_code, :description, 
        (select retail_cost from vw_charge_templates where vw_charge_templates.charge_code = :charge_code))"
    );
    $csv = \League\Csv\Reader::createFromPath( $filepath );
    $nbInsert = $csv->each(function ($row) use (&$sth) {

        //Do not forget to validate your data before inserting it in your database
        $sth->bindValue(':cust_acc', $row[0], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':cli', $row[1], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':charge_date', $row[2], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':quantity', $row[4], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':wholesale_cost', $row[5], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':charge_code', $row[6], \PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindValue(':description', $row[7], \PDO::PARAM_STR);

        return $sth->execute(); //if the function return false then the iteration will stop
     });
}
```

It works fine when the charge code exists in the second table, but i need it to complete the loop when it returns false so that i can load the entire document and check later for missing info.  I've tried all manner of case, if/else statements and not ins but i cant get the syntax right and it always stops at my false charge code.

Please help

EDIT:

I think there is a misunderstanding.  Here is the process as it should be:

1: PHP uploads the file into the loop and writes the prepared statement.

2: at each iteration the subquery

```
select retail_cost from vw_charge_templates where vw_charge_templates.charge_code = :charge_code
```

looks for the current charge code in the loaded file within a table (vw_charge_templates) and selects the rate from that row to insert into this query

3: the query is happy and inserts all the data into the $table.

This works fine if the subquery can find the charge_code in the second table, e.g. the file contains charge code 'ABC' it finds 'ABC' in the tbale and everyone is happy.

This will iterate over as many rows as i like provided the charge_code exists.

If i make up a code 'xyz' regardless of which row on the csv i put it the iteration will stop because the loop returns false (as it was designed - not by me)this cna be row 7, or row 345 and it inserts all the rows up to that point perfectly.

What I need is a condition within the subquery to check for the charge_code in the second table and if the code doesn't exist then to substitue a value.  This is a question about the subquery, not the loop.

Comment: you can't reuse the same bind name; give it another name. Call this an answer in its own right.

Comment: "if the function return false then the iteration will stop" - Then don't return it.

Comment: Blindly inserting data and continuing on errors doesn't seem like a very good idea...

Comment: [That's why this guy wears sunglasses at night...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=56HSPQHSqEE) @jeroen Then again; Ray Charles could've made a great coder.

Comment: Thanks for your responses; I am not blindly inserting data, the point is to check whether new charges without my knowledge if there is an existing charge code, the process is fine, if there is not an existing charge code i still need to know to check if we are behind or being falsely charged.

Comment: @fred, i don't believe I am binding the final input, only using another bind as a comparison but I could be wrong, can you expand?  Also as this works until i put in a false code into my original imported file I think it might be something else?

Comment: `:charge_code` + `:charge_code` = "same bind" in the same query.

Comment: `$sth->execute(); return "This is working very well!";` perhaps? ;-)

Comment: yes but it works until the charge_code cannot be found in the second table, if your hypothesis were correct surely it would never insert a row?

Comment: I think the re-using of named parameters is possible depending on the `emulated prepare` setting or something like that.

Comment: Does it just stop the iteration, or does it stop the script with an error?

Comment: Hi Paul just the iteration no errors

Comment: "The callable must return true to continue iterating over the CSV" ([Reader::each](http://csv.thephpleague.com/8.0/reading/)) - So you can work around it always returning `true` (`$sth->execute(); return true;`). Or do it the right way and check if you can insert the row before you actually do it. `each()` is probably not the best way to do that.

Comment: Thanks Paul, that is helpful, what i am really after is the right way to make the subquery work in the PDO so that if there is not a charge code present in the table it returns an alternative value (it doesn't matter what the value is, its for reference later).  I understand your point about checking before, but the system needs to enter the row regardless as my external supplier charges regardless thus the info is being loaded to check that the charges are correct (they sometimes 'accidentally' charg us for other clients services)